# delete dynamically added values to the ng-repeat(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

First of all, happy thanksgiving to everyone of you !!

I have this plunker-> http://plnkr.co/edit/N2bs5xqmtsj3MmZKEI25?p=info 
User selects all the three values and only then the 'Add' button is enabled for addition.

Once clicked, the entries selected are shown below using ng-repeat. I also a delete button button to every row which gets added. How can i ensure that the delete functionality works in this case. ? i.e. if i click delete, only that particular row will be deleted.

Secondly, if u have noticed during the first add, a single delete button is shown above the first row. how can i remove that?

I also want to save the selected files in the controller so i can give those data to the backend. How can i know which options have been selected by user.

here is the plunker code- 
HTML

```
<div ng-controller="Controller">
<form name="form" novalidate>
     <input type='file' onchange="angular.element(this).scope().fileNameChanged(this)" ng-model="document" valid-file required>
               <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="activeItem.content" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in contentarray" required>
                   <option ng-if="contentarray.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
               </select>

               <select name="singleSelect1" ng-model="activeItem.content1" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in content1array" required>
                   <option ng-if="content1array.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
               </select>
               <button ng-click="addItem()" ng-disabled="disableAdd || (form.$invalid && (!form.$valid && 'invalid' || 'valid'))">Add</button>
</form>

<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="isvisible">
      <a>{{item.name}}</a>
      <a>{{item.content}}</a>
      <a>{{item.content1}}</a>
      <button ng-click="deleteItem()">Delete</button>
</div>
</div>
```

JS code

```
var app = angular.module('Select', []);

app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $timeout) {
/* for adding optional file based selection values selected by the user*/
$scope.isvisible = false;  /* display 1st line  when user clicks on add button*/
$scope.items = [{
}];

$scope.activeItem = {
    name: '',
    content: '',
    content1: ''
}
$scope.fileNameChanged = function (el) {
    $scope.activeItem.name = el.files[0].name
}


$scope.addItem = function () {
    $scope.isvisible = true;
    $scope.items.push($scope.activeItem);
    if ($scope.items.length > 6) {
        $scope.disableAdd = true
    }
    $scope.activeItem = {} /* reset active item*/
    angular.element("input[type='file']").val(null); /* To clear the input type file selected for next selection*/
}




/* for showing select options and enabling add button only when both the options are selected*/
$scope.content = {};
$scope.content1 = {};

$scope.contentarray = ['2', '3'];
$scope.content1array = ['12', '121', '1233', '1211'];

$scope.trigger = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        $('form.bad select').trigger('change');
    })
}

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am referring to your `deleteItem()` and `delete-button`-problem:

You will have to implement your `deleteItem()` method in your controller. `ng-repeat` will automatically update your list, when you delete an item from the model `ìtems`, no need for `angular.element`. This works, because of two-way data-binding in Angular.

Add an id to your `ìtems` and use that to delete the item from the model e.g.:

```
$scope.addItem = function() {
    //...
    $scope.activeItem.id = $scope.items.length;
    $scope.items.push($scope.activeItem);
    //...
}

$scope.deleteItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice(item.id, 1);
}
```

In your `ng-repeat` you need to define your button like this:

```
<button ng-click="deleteItem(item)">Delete</button>
```

Your other problem is with the additional `delete`-button: That is displayed, because you initialize your model `ìtems` with an empty element. Initialize like this instead and the button will not be shown:

```
$scope.items = [];
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This worked brilliantly for me. Thanks for the explanation too.

Comment: Can i save all these values at the controller side ? i.e. i want to know what the user selected. how can i get these ?

Comment: You can save as much data in the controller, as you like. If you like to select an item from your ``<ng-repeat>``-section, then you just need to add a radio-button or checkbox, whatever you prefer and bind that element to a model in your controller. Try something like this e.g.: ``<input type="checkbox" ng-model="items[item.id].checked">``

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand the problem. All the selected data is stored in your controller already. It is added to your model ``$scope.ìtems``. Each time you add a row, that data is also stored in your controller. If you delete data in ``$scope.items``it will automatically delete the according row. Basically ``ng-repeat`` watches ``$scope.items``and everytime that changes, ``ng-repeat`` will run again and update your list.

Comment: yes. now i got it. i wanted to know if deleted rows gets updated. it does because of data binding. thanks guido..